# DataGridView not Clearing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a simple datagridview that I want to update with different data sources when the user clicks different buttons.

To clear the data source I have the below code.

```
dbTableGrid.DataSource = Nothing
dbTableGrid.DataBindings.Clear()
dbTableGrid.Refresh()
```

But the above does not clear the datagridview from the previous loaded data.

The columns remain and no data is displayed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Consider dbTableGrid.Columns.Clear()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this out**

DataGridView.Rows.Clear()
DataGridView.Columns.Clear()